# How to run Amazon Echo inside a private network without AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to use Amazon Echo for a utility project within my company. I have a bunch of intranet sites that I intend to gather information from and develop custom skills to let user query for data. But the client jar (I'm using java) needs to be uploaded to AWS to create a Lambda function and only then that custom skill can be used. This will not work as my jar needs to consume webservices from these intranet systems.

Is there a way to run Echo within the private network without using AWS? I tried to find any relevant information on the internet/stackoverflow, but could not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ended up using secure tunneling to create a publicly accessible url for our internally hosted webservice. It worked like a charm. We used ngrok for this purpose: https://ngrok.com/

Comment: Allowing your service to the public, doesn't compromise your security?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom skill with an endpoint either in Lambda or on a publicly reachable network. So you have a few choices here.

1) You can develop your skill on Lambda, and open up a (suitably secure) gateway in your corporate firewall to allows access to the intranet resources you need.

2) Develop your skill as a web service (using Java, Python, node.js or other language) and host it within your corporate intranet. Then open up a (suitably secure) gateway in your corporate firewall to make that endpoint publicly accessible. Point your skill at that.

2a) There are a lot of complications creating a web endpoint that have to do with SSL certifications. A route many people (including myself) take is to create a [proxy service in Lambda](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/8155/how-to-use-aws-lambda-as-a-proxy-for-non-ssl-serve.html). Your point your skill at Lambda, and then point Lambda at your web service.

Your success with this will mostly depend on how closely you can work with your corporate IT to open holes in your firewall. If you are in a big company, that can be hard. But there really isn't any way around it if you need real-time live access to internal web services.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Opening up holes in firewall is not an option, so did not work for us.

Comment: If you are in a big company, that can be hard. LOL... I know your pain!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, any voice commands directed towards your Amazon Echo device are sent to an Amazon server somewhere on the internet for interpretation.  This server resolves the voice commands and executes the skill, likely in the form of a web service invocation.  The Echo device itself does not invoke the custom web service, instead the Amazon server which the Echo interacted with will call the custom web service.

I believe the Echo device must receive some form of confirmation that the task was executed on the Amazon server either successfully or not.  In some uses, such as "Alexa, what is today's weather?" the Echo device will verbally respond to the end user.  In this scenario the response from the Amazon server back to the Echo device would also contain the verbal response which the Echo device will "speak".  Verbal response data is not mandatory from an Echo implementation perspective.  Some commands are fire and forget and have no verbal response - such as "Alexa, turn TV on."

I guess what I am saying, to get to the point, is that if your web service is on a private network and not accessible outside of your network the Amazon server cannot call your web service.  Even if the Echo device is inside the firewall and on the private network I see no way for the Echo device itself to invoke a web service - these come from the Amazon server somewhere on the internet.

I suspect with more Echo integration (such as in automobiles now) Amazon will consider offering an Echo solution where data can be contained within a private network.

Voice User Interfaces (VUI) are rapidly becoming the next frontier in technology.